# Subquery in view returning more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a view that has a part where it performs a calculation in order to decide which field to bring forth. However, I am running into an issue with the subquery.

Whenever I try to execute the view, I am receiving the error message: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

I understand what it is stating, and typically I would resolve this with a `WHERE` clause and a parameter within the subquery. However, since I am needing to have this as a view, how do I alleviate this issue? I have ran the subqueries independently for multiple cases and verified that they are indeed returning one row per order. Is it possible to have the subquery only select the single result from the present row that it is on in the view?

Here is the code snippet for that particular section of the view. Any advice you guys could offer would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ORC.SimultaneousCalculation = 1
            THEN CASE
                    WHEN -- Select the Owner's Simultaneous Report Code when Sales Price >= Loan Amount.
                        (SELECT
                            CASE 
                                WHEN (ISNULL(O.OwnerPolicyLiability, 0) = 0)
                                    THEN O.SalesPrice
                                WHEN (ISNULL(O.OwnerPolicyLiability, 0) > 0)
                                    THEN (O.OwnerPolicyLiability)
                                ELSE 0 END AS 'SalesPrice'
                                FROM
                                    Orders O) >=
                        (SELECT
                            CASE 
                                WHEN (ISNULL(L.LoanPolicyLiability, 0) = 0)
                                    THEN L.Amount
                                WHEN (ISNULL(L.LoanPolicyLiability, 0) > 0)
                                    THEN (L.Amount)
                                ELSE 0 END AS 'LoanAmount'
                                FROM
                                    Orders O
                                    INNER JOIN Loan L
                                        ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID
                                        AND L.LoanOrder = 1)
                        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),RES.SalesPolicyCode)
                    WHEN -- Select the Owner's Simultaneous Report Code when Sales Price < Loan Amount.
                        (SELECT
                            CASE 
                                WHEN (ISNULL(O.OwnerPolicyLiability, 0) = 0)
                                    THEN O.SalesPrice
                                WHEN (ISNULL(O.OwnerPolicyLiability, 0) > 0)
                                    THEN (O.OwnerPolicyLiability)
                                ELSE 0 END AS 'SalesPrice'
                                FROM
                                    Orders O) <
                        (SELECT
                            CASE 
                                WHEN (ISNULL(L.LoanPolicyLiability, 0) = 0)
                                    THEN L.Amount
                                WHEN (ISNULL(L.LoanPolicyLiability, 0) > 0)
                                    THEN (L.Amount)
                                ELSE 0 END AS 'LoanAmount'
                                FROM
                                    Orders O
                                    INNER JOIN Loan L
                                        ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID
                                        AND L.LoanOrder = 1)
                        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),RES.LoanPolicyCode)
                    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),0) END
        -- If not Simultaneous, select the primary rate's Report Code.
        ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),R.ReportCode)
        END AS 'PremCode'
    ,O.Col1
    ,O.Col2
    ,O.Col3
FROM
    Orders O
    INNER JOIN OrderRateCalculation ORC
        ON O.OrdersID = ORC.OrdersID
    LEFT JOIN Rate R
        ON ORC.RateID = R.RateID
    LEFT JOIN RateEffectiveDate RED
        ON R.RateID = RED.RateID
    LEFT JOIN RateEngineSimultaneous RES
        ON RED.RateEffectiveDateID = RES.RateEffectiveDateID
WHERE
    (ORC.LoanHolder = 1)
```

Comment: This is only a portion of the view? Why are there so many nested case expressions? This really makes it hard to follow. I suspect that most of the issue is because your subqueries are not correlated. There should be a where clause on them to limit the results to be related to the outer query.

Comment: The problem is that some of your subquerys are returnin more that one row, so SQL server does not know wich row to compare with. You can use MAX or MIN to filter the subquery to one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without more knowledge of your tables' relationships, but if it were me, I would try to find a way to move the JOIN to 'Loan' to the primary join list, and remove the subselects altogether. Something like this:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN ORC.SimultaneousCalculation = 1
        THEN CASE
                WHEN -- Select the Owner's Simultaneous Report Code when Sales Price >= Loan Amount.
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (ISNULL(O.OwnerPolicyLiability, 0) = 0)
                                THEN O.SalesPrice
                            WHEN (ISNULL(O.OwnerPolicyLiability, 0) > 0)
                                THEN (O.OwnerPolicyLiability)
                            ELSE 0 END AS 'SalesPrice'
                         >=
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (ISNULL(L.LoanPolicyLiability, 0) = 0)
                                THEN L.Amount
                            WHEN (ISNULL(L.LoanPolicyLiability, 0) > 0)
                                THEN (L.Amount)
                            ELSE 0 END AS 'LoanAmount'
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),RES.SalesPolicyCode)
                WHEN -- Select the Owner's Simultaneous Report Code when Sales Price < Loan Amount.
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (ISNULL(O.OwnerPolicyLiability, 0) = 0)
                                THEN O.SalesPrice
                            WHEN (ISNULL(O.OwnerPolicyLiability, 0) > 0)
                                THEN (O.OwnerPolicyLiability)
                            ELSE 0 END AS 'SalesPrice'
                         <
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (ISNULL(L.LoanPolicyLiability, 0) = 0)
                                THEN L.Amount
                            WHEN (ISNULL(L.LoanPolicyLiability, 0) > 0)
                                THEN (L.Amount)
                            ELSE 0 END AS 'LoanAmount'
                    THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),RES.LoanPolicyCode)
                ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),0) END
    -- If not Simultaneous, select the primary rate's Report Code.
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),R.ReportCode)
    END AS 'PremCode'
,O.Col1
,O.Col2
,O.Col3
FROM
Orders O
INNER JOIN OrderRateCalculation ORC
    ON O.OrdersID = ORC.OrdersID
LEFT JOIN Rate R
    ON ORC.RateID = R.RateID
LEFT JOIN RateEffectiveDate RED
    ON R.RateID = RED.RateID
LEFT JOIN RateEngineSimultaneous RES
    ON RED.RateEffectiveDateID = RES.RateEffectiveDateID
LEFT JOIN Loan L
    ON O.OrdersID = L.OrdersID
    AND L.LoanOrder = 1
WHERE
(ORC.LoanHolder = 1)
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Bingo! I'm not sure why this didn't cross my mind. I think I incorrectly assumed I wouldn't be able to compare two CASE statements against each other, but that was just a simple lapse in mind. Thank you, sir!